# Multiple differing views of the same list

Tags: java, variable-assignment, comparator, genetic-algorithm, knapsack-problem

I'm trying to make iterators for a class called Ship. This is for a genetic algorithm example.

The two key attributes of Ship are weight and volume (knapsack problem). I want one iterator sorting by weight, and one by volume.

I am having trouble setting up the implements `Comparable<(?)>` interface for the Ship class.

At first I tried to pass a Class called Value which has an enum representing its type and a float value. I have a `CompareTo` method that looks like this:

```
return int CompareTo(Value arg0)

 switch (arg0.type())

 case WEIGHT:
  return this._weight.compareTo(arg0.value);

...
```

Comment: See example available on [internet](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Java-Beginners/26582-Java-Comparable-Example.html)

Comment: The example you gave was for using the Comparable (which I exampled there, but as the question went I was looking to have two of these method. If the admins can show a duplicate of my question then great. But ultimately I just got cookie cuttered because I didn't approach in the most formal of way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better of having two comparators one comparing based on weight and one based on volume and the use those comparators to sort on demand.

Comment: Thanks you are 100% correct. I was outlining the code I had got stuck on. I was using the comparable derived comparator but instead I can create a new one with the Ship object and the enum